# Center of free group (of rank greater than 1) is trivial

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I am currently reading through a solution of the following problem and I am having a bit of trouble. The problem is as follows:

> Let $S$ be a set and $F$ be the free group on $S$. Show that if $|S| > 1$, then $Z(F)$ is trivial.

In order to deduce a contradiction, suppose that $w \in Z(F) \setminus \{e\}$ (where $e$ is the identity element). Let $w = a_{1}^{\pm1} \cdots a_{n}^{\pm 1}$ be the reduced word expression for $w$. Since $w \in Z(F)$, we have 
$$
\left(a_{n-1}^{\mp 1} \cdots a_{1}^{\mp 1} \right)w = w\left(a_{n-1}^{\mp 1} \cdots a_{1}^{\mp 1} \right).
$$
Now the left-hand side reduces to 
$$
\left(a_{n-1}^{\mp 1} \cdots a_{1}^{\mp 1} \right)w = \left(a_{n-1}^{\mp 1} \cdots a_{1}^{\mp 1} \right)\left(a_{1}^{\pm1} \cdots a_{n}^{\pm 1} \right) = a_{n}^{ \pm 1}.
$$
Comparing this to the right-hand side, we deduce that it must be the case that $a_{n}^{\pm 1}=a_{n-1}^{\pm 1} = \cdots = a_{1}^{\pm 1}$; so write $w = \left(a_{1}^{\pm 1}\right)^n$.

[Now every part of the proof makes sense to me thus far, but I do not see the rationale for the coming part.]

> Since $|S| > 1$, let $b \in S$ be such that $a_{1}^{\pm 1} \neq b$. Then $wb = bw$ because $w \in Z(F)$, and so $\left( a_{1}^{\pm1} \right)^n b = b\left(a_{1}^{\pm 1} \right)^n$. However this implies that $a_{1}^{\pm 1} = b$, which is a contradiction.

I cannot see how to deduce that $a_{1}^{\pm 1} = b$ from $\left( a_{1}^{\pm1} \right)^n b = b\left(a_{1}^{\pm 1} \right)^n$. The solution says to consider the reduced words, but this does not seem to be very helpful considering $\left( a_{1}^{\pm1} \right)^n b$ and $b\left( a_{1}^{\pm1} \right)^n$ are already reduced.

Comment: @DietrichBurde While the question is the same, I am trying to understand a specific part of a solution and it is different from the approach in that question. Moreover, the accepted answer in that question is not recognized by a number of users (as indicated by the comments).

Comment: Just take Jyrki's first comment as a good answer. It has $7$ upvotes at the duplicate (and is the same answer as the one given here below, so it looks like a duplicate for me).

Answer (score 1):

The reduced word for $bw$ begins with $b$. The reduced word for $wb$ does not. So $bw\ne wb$ and $w$ cannot lie in the centre.